# How to handle popScope in a modal in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a tiktok clone using flutter and i'm currently working on the comment section. so i separated the sidebarItems to handle them properly. and now for the comment i'm trying to work on the keyboard. the keybord is difficult to handle coz the whole container that holds the text field, profil picture and send button should move on top of the keyboard.

so inorder to do that i need to hide the body where the comment is and resize it by using the focusNode. and it works.

but now i'm facing that when the user taps on back key from the device, the keyboard closes but the focusNode doesn't change. so i tried popScope by wraping the commment button. but doesn't do anything. how can i handle that form the button itself?

```
PopScope(
              canPop: true,
              onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
                print(
                    "pop screen is trigered and works fine so don't worry about a thing.");
                if (didPop) {
                  return;
                }
                _focusNode.unfocus();
              },
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (_isKeyboardVisible) {
                    _focusNode.unfocus();
                  } else {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        isScrollControlled: true,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                            ),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                              onTap: () {
                                if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
                                  _focusNode.unfocus();
                                }
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: _focusNode.hasFocus
                                    ? height * 0.2
                                    : height * 0.6,
                                width: width,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                    )),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                                "${widget.video["commentsCount"]} comments ${_focusNode.hasFocus}"))),
                                    !_focusNode.hasFocus
                                        ? Expanded(flex: 5, child: Text("BODY"))
                                        : Container(
                                            height: 0.001,
                                          ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            height: iconSize,
                                            width: iconSize,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: NetworkImage(widget
                                                                .video['user']
                                                            ['profilePic'] ==
                                                        ""
                                                    ? 'https://picsum.photos/id/1062/400/400'
                                                    : widget.video['user']
                                                        ['profilePic']),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: width * 0.02,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    vertical: height * 0.015),
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: width * 0.03),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            50)),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Expanded(
                                                        child: Center(
                                                      child: TextField(
                                                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .transparent),
                                                        decoration:
                                                            InputDecoration(
                                                          border:
                                                              InputBorder.none,
                                                          hintText:
                                                              "Add comments...",
                                                        ),
                                                        textInputAction:
                                                            TextInputAction
                                                                .done,
                                                        onEditingComplete: () {
                                                          _focusNode.unfocus();
                                                        },
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
                                                    IconButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {},
                                                        icon: Icon(
                                                          Icons.send,
                                                          color: Colors.teal,
                                                        ))
                                                  ],
                                                )),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: iconSize,
                  width: iconSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("assets/images/comment.png"))),
                ),
              ),
            )
```